# How can I still run a custom IBundleTransform when EnableOptimization is off in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, templates, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-optimization

First the background - I'm using Handlebars for templating HTML and I want to make use of the bundling and caching capabilities of ASP.NET Bundling to deliver the templates to the client. To that end I've created my own `Bundle` subclass and an implementation of `IBundleTransform` that does some necessary conversion of my templates. In particular I:

1. add the templates to visual studio as HTML but embed the template in a `<script type='text/x-handlebars-template'>...</script>` which seems to give me great template/html intellisense
2. in my implementation of `IBundleTransform` I wrap the final template in something along the lines of `Injector.register('{0}', function() {{ return window.atob('{1}'); }});` where `{0}` is replaced with the path of the template and is used to fetch the template in client code and `{1}` is replaced with a base64 encoded form of the HTML (until I can figure out a better way of encoding the html string!)

My problem comes if I set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false` at which point none of number 2 above occurs and I'm delivered the raw file. I've temporarily resorted to the following code which stops minification of all files but still transforms them :

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;    
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    foreach (var bundle in bundles)
    {
        if (bundle.Path != "~/bundles/handlebars-templates")
                  bundle.Transforms.Clear();
    }
}
```

Is there a better option that allows me to turn optimizations off, deliver all my templates individually to the browser but still have them transformed before they go?

Comment: Did you end up finding an answer to this? I have a custom transform that's supposed to replace some values in a css files. The transform is being run correctly, but when the scripts are rendered, the untransformed value is output.

Comment: Unfortunately I still don't have an answer :(