# Bundle transformation applied after the bundle is already added

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-bundling

I have the following setup

```
public class TrackingTransform : IBundleTransform
{
    public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse response)
    {
        const string apiTokenPlaceHolder = "{{ApiToken}}";
        var token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Token"];

        response.Content = response.Content.Replace(apiTokenPlaceHolder, token);
    }
}
```

And add the transform to my bundle

```
var trackingBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/tracking/global").Include(
            "~/Scripts/mdb.mixpanel.js",
            "~/Scripts/mdb.tracking.global-handlers.js"
            );

        trackingBundle.Transforms.Add(new TrackingTransform());
        bundles.Add(trackingBundle);
```

Then I reference the bundle in the view like this

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/tracking/global")
```

When debugging I can see that the `{{ApiToken}}` is replaced with the correct value in the `response.Content` but when I look at the script in the browser I still see the original placeholder.

I noticed that the `bundles.Add(trackingBundle)` is executed before the `Process()` method which is probably the reason for the problem. However I can't seem to find out why this is happening and how to fix it.

I was originally following [this article](http://evolutionarydeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/config-settings-into-javascript-using.html) even the Microsoft's [docs](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification) suggest the same thing

Comment: Updated the question with the way I reference the bundle

Comment: Oops - just deleted my original comment by mistake! I would expect `bundles.Add` (when the bundle is created) to execute before `Process` (when it is requested). What you've written should definitely work. If you try to visit the bundle directly in the browser, and stick a breakpoint on the `Process` method, does it do the replacement then? Are you running the site in debug or release mode?

Comment: I am currently running in debug and I can see the different javascript files in the browser instead of 1 big bundle not sure if that has anything to do with it

Comment: Can you see if it works with bundling/minification on? ie - `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` added as the first line in your `RegisterBundles` method?

Comment: So that made the transformation work but is there a way to do that without bundling the files when debugging?

Comment: @AdrianHristov - I guess there should be, but this question appears to suggest otherwise. http://stackoverflow.com/q/28632692/3130094. You can try the approach there though.

Comment: @AdrianHristov - This also looks promising. Some good info in this question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26769287/3130094